# How to make dynamic rowspan codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have table rowspan dynamic on CodeIgniter app like this :

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>No</td>
    <td>Data 1</td>
    <td>Data 2</td>
    <td>Qty</td>
    <td>Data 3</td>
</tr>
<?php

$source1 = $this->db->query("select * from table")->result_array(); 
$no=1;
foreach($source1 as source1){ ?>
    <tr>
        <?php 
        $source2 = $this->db->query("select * from table where data1='$source1[data1]'");
        $total_source2 = $source2->num_rows();
        $source3 = $source2->result_array();
        ?>
        <td rowspan="<?php echo $total_source2 ?>"><?php echo $no; ?></td>
        <td rowspan="<?php echo $total_source2 ?>"><?php echo $source1['data1']; ?></td>
        <?php foreach($source3 as $source3){ ?>
            <td><?php echo $source3['data2'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $source3['qty'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $source3['data3'] ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php $no++; } ?>
</table>
```

This is result of my code:

[image: table 1]

How to make it like this :

[image: table 2]

?

Thanks

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Post your code as a [mcve]! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Answer (score 2):

```css
table {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

table td,
table th {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr> 
    <th>No</th>
    <th>Data1</th> 
    <th>Data2</th> 
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Sub Total</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
    <td rowspan="2">1</td> 
    <td rowspan="2">ABCDE</td> 
    <td>Data2 a</td> 
    <td>1</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td rowspan="2">620</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
    <td>Data2 b</td> 
    <td>4</td> 
    <td>130</td> 
    <td>152</td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td rowspan="3">2</td> 
    <td rowspan="3">ABC</td> 
    <td>Data2 c</td> 
    <td>2</td>
    <td>400</td>
    <td>800</td>
    <td rowspan="3">1560</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
    <td>Data2 d</td> 
    <td>2</td> 
    <td>200</td> 
    <td>400</td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td>Data2 e</td> 
    <td>3</td> 
    <td>120</td> 
    <td>360</td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td>3</td> 
    <td>ASS</td> 
    <td>Data 2 f</td> 
    <td>1</td> 
    <td>100</td> 
    <td>100</td> 
    <td>100</td> 
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Sorry, that is no dynamic. just on html.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have to apply row-span or col-span then always try to write that  content outside of for-each

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>No</td>
    <td>Data 1</td>
    <td>Data 2</td>
    <td>Qty</td>
    <td>Data 3</td>
</tr>
<?php

$source1 = $this->db->query("select * from table")->result_array(); 
$no=1;
foreach($source1 as source1){ ?>
    <tr>
        <?php 
        $source2 = $this->db->query("select * from table where data1='$source1[data1]'");
        $total_source2 = $source2->num_rows();
        $source3 = $source2->result_array();
        ?>
        <td rowspan="<?php echo $total_source2 ?>"><?php echo $no; ?></td>
        <td rowspan="<?php echo $total_source2 ?>"><?php echo $source1['data1']; ?></td>
        <?php foreach($source3 as $source3){ ?>
            <td><?php echo $source3['data2'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $source3['qty'] ?></td>
    <?php } ?>
   <td rowspan="<?php echo $total_source2 ?>"><?php echo $source3['data3'] ?></td>
   </tr>
    <?php $no++; } ?>
</table>
```